# How can I select the monday date for this current week using MySQL / MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, date, mariadb

Using MySQL or MariaDB, how can I get the date for Monday of this current week?

I would like to see something returned by the query like: '2020-04-27'.

Comment: But remember that sql is for the storage and retrieval of data, and not much else

Comment: @Strawberry I set this result to a variable and then use that for other queries on large datasets.

Answer (score 2):

**If you count Monday as the first day of the week:**

> `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1),'Monday'), '%x%v %W');`

**If you count Sunday as the first day of the week:**

> `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),'Monday'), '%X%V %W');`